# Javaswing button decrease value of JTextfield/JLabel

Tags: java, swing, button, jtextfield

```
private void jButton6ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    int full = 20;
    int feed = -10;
    int jHooitemp = Integer.parseInt(jHooi1.getText());
    jHooi1.setText(jHooitemp+ feed+ " kg");
}
```

I managed to decrease the pre defined value of the `JTextfield`(jHooi1) but it only works once.

It made the value wich i entered(20) drop to 10. but if i press the `JButton` another time it displays errors in the run screen.

Is there a way to make it decrease to 0 and send a message when it hits 0?

Comment: *"..but it only works once."*  Is the code ignoring exception output?  Note that the `kg` in `jHooi1.setText(jHooitemp+ feed+ " kg");` would mean that next time the method is called, `int jHooitemp = Integer.parseInt(jHooi1.getText());` will **not** contain an 'integer'.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) Always copy/paste error and exception output!

Comment: This is the exact same code posted by kjens (<http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33302110/manipulating-numbers-in-jlabel-or-jtextfield-on-button-click>) an hour before!